# Weird terminal bug(?) - have to control+c after every command

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, iterm2, iterm

I'm having a weird issue with **both** terminal and iterm, where when I `cd` into a specific directory (and every subfolder), I have to `control+c` to 'exit' after every command that I run, and only then can I continue with an actual command (like `ls` or `cd` whatever). This happens in any subfolder under the one specific root directory.

I'm not sure what state it puts me in when I have to `control+c`, it's just an empty line where I can enter text, if I press enter it just goes to the next line. Only way to exit it and continue running commands is to hit `control+c`, but when I run another command, I have to `control+c` to exit again. So it gets pretty annoying having to `control+c` after every single command. It also happens to be the directory with all my work in it, so I use it all the time.

Sorry if that's a terrible/confusing explanation, it's sorta hard to explain what's happening here. Thanks in advance for any help!

also for what it's worth - I'm OSX/zsh/oh-my-zsh/iterm instead of terminal usually

edit - just checked, this same thing happens in the vs code terminal as well...

Comment: You mention cmd+c, are you doing this on OSX, or do you mean control+c ? Either way, it sounds like your terminal prompt maybe messed up.

Comment: whoops you're right, I meant control+c. I am on OSX. will update the question

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out - I had control+c'd/stopped in the middle of a `git push` earlier, and that might have been when this issue started. because now when I just did a `git add *`, everything seems to have gone back to normal. I'm guessing that it was still caught up in the middle of the `git push` or something